# Div Cards Overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

`Div` Card overlap each other when I reduce the screen size on certain degree. But after I reduce it even more, it works as I want it to be . this is how it looks when I reduce it to the point so bootstrap can work on `col-md`

This is problem

[image]

This is how it normaly is:

[image]

```css
.cards {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.cards h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-smooth: auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #444;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 265px;
  height: 360px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure:before,
figure:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

figure:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 0;
}

figure:after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure:hover {
  background-size: 175%;
}

figure:hover:after {
  content: "read more";
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.9);
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  z-index: 2;
}

figure:hover .date {
  bottom: -59px;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  transform: translateY(-110%);
}

.cards p {
  display: none;
}

.cards p:hover {
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}

figure .date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(241, 196, 15, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}

figure .date span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 1;
}

figure .date span:first-child {
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

figure .date span:last-child {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

figure figcaption {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  z-index: 1;
}

figure figcaption h4 {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.35;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

figure figcaption h4>span {
  /* background-color: rgba(241, 196, 15, 0.8); */
}

figure figcaption p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cards">
  <h1>What We Offer</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <a class="" href="#">
        <figure style='background-image: url("offers/conference.jpg")'>
          <figcaption>
            <h4> <span>Conference halls</span></h4>
            <p></p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <a class="" href="#">
        <figure style='background-image: url("offers/restaurant.jpg")'>
          <figcaption>
            <h4> <span>Restaurant & Bar</span></h4>
            <p></p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <a class="" href="#">
        <figure style='background-image: url("offers/entertainment.jpg")'>
          <figcaption>
            <h4> <span>Entertainment room</span></h4>
            <p></p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <a class="" href="#">
        <figure style='background-image: url("offers/spa.jpg")'>
          <figcaption>
            <h4> <span>Spa & Wellness</span></h4>
            <p></p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is happening due to fixed width in "figure" tag (265px), make width "100%" or "auto". Please try it.

Comment: aah thanks with your help and some modifications and resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your snippet, what I have noticed that you have given fixed width value to "figure" tag in CSS (265px). Due to which it is causing overlay on column parent div. Just update width with "auto" or make it "100%", i hope it will resolve. I have added updated snippet below, please try it.

```
figure {

position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 360px;
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 20px 20px;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 14px 28px}
```